# How to remove parentheses around pandoc citations?

Tags: lua, latex, pandoc

Here's how I do my citations in latex

```tex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber, style=apa, 
    giveninits=true, uniquename=init,
    citestyle=authoryear]{biblatex}
\bibliography{references.bib} 

\begin{document}
... catastrophic population declines (\cite{McIntyre__2015}).
\end{document}
```

I'm using pandoc to convert this to `docx` or `odt` so I can get track changes from colleagues.

```sh
pandoc ./main.tex -f latex -t odt --bibliography=./references.bib --csl ../apa.csl -o output.odt
```

However... in the resulting document, pandoc automatically surrounds every `\cite` call with an extra set of parenthesis.

> ...catastrophic population declines ((McIntyre et al. 2015)).

I really like doing parentheses manually... is there a way for me to get pandoc to stop adding these extra citation parentheses?

I have the impression that this can be done with lua filters in pandoc...  I was hoping someone could give me some pointers in the right direction on how to address this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer from `tarleb` didn't solve the question, but it did lead me to the [right documentation](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html#type-citation).

I now understand that pandoc relies on CSL for the actual formatting of citations, while lua filters can modify what *kind* of citation is used (author in text, vs author in parenthesis).

```xml
<citation et-al-min="3" et-al-use-first="1" disambiguate-add-year-suffix="true" disambiguate-add-names="true" disambiguate-add-givenname="true" collapse="year" givenname-disambiguation-rule="primary-name-with-initials">
    <layout prefix="" suffix="" delimiter="; ">
    </layout>
  </citation>
```

In my CSL doc, I just removed the parentheses from the `prefix` and `suffix` attributes of the `<citation> <layout>` node.
Now only my manually placed parentheses appear in the compiled doc.

> ...catastrophic population declines (McIntyre et al., 2015).

Answer (score 2):

A Lua filter could be used to change the citation mode such that the parens are omitted:

```lua
function Cite(cite)
  for _, c in ipairs(cite.citations) do
    c.mode = pandoc.AuthorInText
  end
  return cite
end
```

Make sure that the filter runs before `citeproc`, i.e., it must occur first in the call to pandoc:

```
pandoc --lua-filter=modify-citations.lua --citeproc ...
```

---

The alternative would be to change `\cite` into `\citet`.

Comment: thanks for this!  However, it only removes the author from parenthesis, while still leaving them on the year.  From this answer tho, I just realised that `lua` filters aren't really the correct approach for this.